# Fetching facebook notifications in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I am creating an android application for fetching Facebook notifications. Here, once the user is logged in, I want to fetch the user's Facebook notifications and display them in my application.

How is this possible?

I saw a sample code in [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com), but it requires **manage_notifications** permission. I am confused about adding that permission.

When i run the application, I got this message in my log:

`an active access token must be used to query information about the current user`.

How to fix this ?

Comment: didnt you watch the tutorials that i told you to see that.???

Comment: oye mil gaya mjhe...come on gmail..

Comment: :-/..why dont you check your account...:*

Comment: there..........................

Comment: oye kahan gai...i need ssl link..???

Comment: can you tell me what you had done for facebook notification in your android app notification bar